# Learning or Training on Microservices

Tags: microservices

Can anyone please suggest good learning or paid training site for good understanding on microservice including CI/CD and deploying to kubernates /docker using circuit breaker , auto-scaling and deploying to any cloud provider.

Comment: this could be helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/

Comment: you can find mentors at https://www.mentorgee.com/ , they connect you with industry people working on the same things. I tried that and worked really well for me in Deep Learning.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good sources from where you can learn these things. 
If you are looking for a Online Course/Learning platform the most popular ones are
Udemy and Pluralsight. There are some others but I used these and they where very helpful.

Now if all this topics are in one course and if you will find a guide which includes all them in one course is possible but I did
not fine one.

Instead what you can do is have a couple of separate courses to cover these topics:

1. Microservices archticture - which is actually a big topic on its own
   Here is one from Udemy:
   https://www.udemy.com/microservices-software-architecture-patterns-and-techniques/
   Here is one from Pluralsight:
   https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/microservices-architecture/table-of-contents
2. Kubernetes(includes some docker, autoscaling)
   Here is one from Udemy:
   https://www.udemy.com/kubernetes-microservices/
   Here is one from Pluralsight:
   https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/docker-kubernetes-big-picture/table-of-contents

These are just examples. There are plenty more courses which you can pick depending on your
experience level on those topics.